# opening an emergent window in WPF application

Tags: .net, wpf

I want to open window2.xaml from the window1.xaml window as an emergent (floating) window. 
In winforms that was form2.show() , how do I do it in WPF for both WPF application and WPFbrowser application? 
(I assume it's different for WPF application and WPFbrowser application)

Comment: Are you trying to do it in XAML? Or the code behind in C#?

Comment: I was trying to do it from the codebehind but I dont care how it's done, I just want to do it. If it can be done from the interface xaml it's fine for me, though I dont know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not much different in WPF than winforms. The method itself is still Show() for a WPF window.

```
Button btnClick = new Button();
btnClick.Click +=  btnClick_Click;

void btnClick_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        window2 exampleWindow = new window2();
        exampleWindow.Show();
    }
```

You pick where you want to instantiate and show the window depending on how you want your program to operate.

**Update:**

In a WPF web app you have ChildWindows. If you create your own custom window which inherits ChildWindow it will call just like any other window in a WPF app. The method is once again.

```
exampleChildWindow.Show();
```

Comment: thanks, I also would like to do the same for a WPF application, but it's different for that type of application, right? how do I do it in a WPF application? (web)